# Get class(es) of active item in Fancybox 2 Callback

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get the class(es) of the current active fancybox link through the beforeLoad callback.

HTML example:

```
<a href="example.png" class="lightbox pdf-opening">Link</a>
<a href="example2.png" class="lightbox pdf-closing">Link</a>
```

jQuery/Fancybox code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".lightbox").fancybox(
        {
            beforeLoad: function(){
                var pdf_type_string = $(".lightbox").eq(this.index).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
                var test = pdf_type_string.toString();
                var pdf_type = test.substr(4);
                alert(pdf_type);
            },
            title: '<a class="lightbox_link_to_tickets" href="/your-visit/booking-online/">Book your tickets here</a>',
            type: 'image'
        }
    );

});
```

this.index always returns 0, even when clicking the second link, which (in theory to me) should return 1 when clicking the second link...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Paul

**Solution**

The solution for me was the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fancybox(
    {
        beforeLoad: function(){
            var pdf_type_object = $(this.element).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
            var pdf_type_string = pdf_type_object.toString();
            var pdf_type = pdf_type_string.substr(4);
            this.title = '<a class="lightbox_link_to_tickets" href="/your-visit/booking-online/">Book your tickets here</a> - <a class="lightbox_link_to_tickets" href="/inc/images/your-visit/timetables-and-fares/'+pdf_type+'.pdf">Downloadable PDF</a>';
        },
        type: 'image'
        }
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access current element like:

```
beforeLoad: function() {
    console.info( $(this.element) );
}
```

Comment: Cheers! This works for me! I had a feeling this.index wasn't quite what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var pdf_type_string = $(".lightbox").eq($(this).index(this)).attr('class')
```

Comment: Hi. Sadly, no, this also returns the classes of the first link even when I click the second...